# How do I develop for both Portrait and Landscape display formats?

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp, landscape, portrait

I'm currently developing for a handheld device running Windows XP Professional (not Tablet PC edition). The device allows users to switch from the standard widescreen landscape display format to a portrait one. I would like to know if there are any VB.NET code snippets to help me along with this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to determine the current orientation is with the          `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation` property.

To get the actual size of the screen, check `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height` (and `.Width`)

You can declare an event handler (with the `AddHandler` statement) for `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` as a trigger your app can respond to, and then check the screen orientation to see if you need to adjust your GUI layout.